# Laravel homestead git clone not working

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have git cloned an existing project to my vagrant homestead machine, have setup Homestead.yaml and hosts file and run vagrant provision, but first I got this error:

```
Warning: require(/home/vagrant/Projects/MyProject/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/Projects/MyProject/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

After looking around I saw that alot of the times solution would be just to run

```
 composer install
```

or

```
composer update
```

I did that, but I just got an error after that:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

In console I checked it says:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Have you tried composer dump-autoload?

Comment: I tried it now, but it doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: just delete the `vendor` folder and run composer install

Comment: I did that as well, but still the same thing.

Comment: Checked the logs? Also be sure all necessary folder permissions are set correctly

Comment: @Marco Have you found solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `composer.lock` and run `composer install` again.

Answer (score 0):

run this command

```
php artisan config:clear
```